# How can I be sure an email address is unique?

Tags: email, email-validation

There's a pub in my town whereby, if you sign up to their newsletter using their website and provide a "unique" email address, you get a free drink.  On a whim, I decided to sign up a second time using `myemail+one@gmail.com`.  It let me.  I'm now sitting on a nice comfy pile of free drink vouchers.

This got me thinking about a system we have here, where the email address is considered the unique identifier.  Checking the code, sure enough, if we were offering vouchers in our business, someone *else* would be sitting pretty.

The basic, stab-in-the-dark, fix is to check for the "+" character and ignore everything after it (up to the `@`), and compare using that.  But I am unsure if this was the *intent* for the `+` character.  Would that work?

Secondly, are there any other caveats that would allow a user to sign up multiple times with a seemingly different email address, but which actually would always end up in the same mailbox?

This question is language-agnostic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While using a plus sign as an e-mail address alias is a known feature of gmail, other mailers do either not allow it or use a minus sign instead. '+' is a legitimate character to be used as part of an email address according to the RFC.

The use of '.' is also a gray area. john.doe@gmail.com and johndoe@gmail.com send also both to the same email address and look different.

In order to validate the uniqueness of an email address you will have to prepare a rule base for your application, keep it up to date and still expect surprises...